# what the running time of this recursive algorithm?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

```
Search_item(A,item,c)

index <- c   

If (A[index] > item)
Then 
      index <- 2 * index
      Search_item(A, item, index)
Else
If (A[index] < item)
Then 
      index <- 2 * index + 1
      Search_item(A, item, index)
Else

Return index
```

Comment: It would totally depend on how fast your processor is, regardless of the implementation, so we can't really tell you.

Comment: That's an illustrative example.  We can't give you an actual answer.  You might as well have given a diagram of an engine and asked how fast the car would go. Test it and find out for yourself on your own hardware.

Comment: Presumably you want the big-O complexity, correct? Also, what do you think it is, and why? And I don't know if you have some weird fonts installed, or there's just something wrong with my browser, but the code you posted looks really weird - I took a stab at fixing it, feel free to correct it if I did so incorrectly.

Comment: I would guess it does a binary search in sorted array A using recursion. This looks like O(log n) intuitively because of the 2*index which is logarithmic for recursion functions. You can calculate the recurrence relation and insert your recurrence formula in http://www.wolframalpha.com which will give you the Big-O running time. Alternatively you could do imperical test with random data and get an idea of the running time.

Answer (score 0):

You gave very little (no) information. This is very sad, but I will give an answer and hope you will show more effort in other questions, as I show effort in answering your question.

The algorithm you posted seems to be incomplete. I think there are some `Return`s missing. However:

The simplest complexity analysis is this:
You work on an array `A`. Let `n` be the number of elements in `A`. In every recursive call you are either multiplying the current index by two (and make another recursive call) or you return the current index.
Assuming your algorithm is correct, you can have only `k` recursive calls with `2k < n`. So `k < log₂(n)` holds.

This means your algorithm has a time-complexity of `O(log n)`.

Since your algorithm is a named as a "search" algorithm, it looks like the array `A` is a representation of a binary search tree and your search algorithm is a recursive binary search.
This fits the complexity I calculated.